# SSL peer certificate validation failed: unable to get local issuer certificate in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to configure the SSL certificates in MongoDB. For that, I took sample domain-name like myapptest.tk using freenom(online) and generated certificates for that domain-name using sslforfree(online). Assigned that domain-name to my MongoDB server IP in /etc/hosts file. After that Downloaded those certificates and configured them in /etc/mongod.conf file.

Here are my SSL configurations which I have used in mongod.conf

```
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0  # Enter 0.0.0.0,:: to bind to all IPv4 and IPv6 
 addresses or, alternatively, use the net.bindIpAll setting.
  ssl:
    mode: requireSSL
    PEMKeyFile: /etc/ssl/mongodb.pem
    CAFile: /etc/ssl/ca_bundle.crt
    allowConnectionsWithoutCertificates: false
    allowInvalidHostnames: false
    disabledProtocols: TLS1_0,TLS1_1
```

Here I am converting certificate.crt and private.key into mongodb.pem and passing as the value of PEMKeyFile and passing ca_bundle.crt as the value of  CAFile. Finally restarted the mongod service using the command

```
 sudo service mongod restart
```

mongodb server running successfully. Now I am trying to connect with mongodb server through the command

```
mongo --ssl --sslPEMKeyFile /etc/ssl/mongodb.pem --sslCAFile /etc/ssl/ca_bundle.crt --host myapptest.tk
```

I am unable to connect to the server. Getting the error like

> MongoDB shell version v4.0.8
>
> connecting to: mongodb://myapptest.tk:27017/?gssapiServiceName=mongodb
>
> 2019-04-04T19:57:40.401+0000 E NETWORK  [js] SSL peer certificate validation failed: unable to get local issuer certificate
>
> 2019-04-04T19:57:40.402+0000 E QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect to server myapptest.tk:27017, connection attempt failed: SSLHandshakeFailed: SSL peer certificate validation failed: unable to get local issuer certificate :
>
> connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:343:13
>
> @(connect):2:6
>
> exception: connect failed

If I am using the mongo command with the option `--sslAllowInvalidCertificates` like

```
mongo --ssl --sslAllowInvalidCertificates
```

I can able to connect with the mongodb server, otherwise, I was unable to connect with the server.

What's the wrong with configuring the SSL certificates in mongod.conf file?

what I want is, Can we able to connect with the MongoDB server with --sslCAFile?

How to generate the --sslPEMKeyfile and --sslCAFile in *.pem formats in mongodb?

Below was the link which I have followed:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/configure-ssl/

Could anybody suggest me to achieve this?

Comment: Hey did you found a solution, the same thing happening for me?

Comment: I am also getting the same issue.